# Android RecyclerView item selection issue

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am designing a live quiz app that fetches data from server and question are displayed in a `RecyclerView` that contains a question and four options. Now when I select one option for a given question, it is selected properly but at the same time, the corresponding option for other question is selected automatically.

Screenshot of the item selection issue is the following.

[image]

Here is the adapter class of my RecyclerView

```
public class LiveTestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LiveTestAdapter.CustomViewHolder>{
    private int mItemSelected=-1;
    private List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList;
    DmLiveQuiz questionsList; // DmLiveQuiz questionsList
    private Context context; //context
    final DataHolder dh=new DataHolder();
    public List<Integer> myResponse= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int qno;
    public String myQno;
    public int afterSub;
    DataHolder dataHolder;

    public LiveTestAdapter(List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList, Context context) {
        this.questionList = questionList;
        this.context = context; 
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.live_quiz_display_format,parent,false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CustomViewHolder holder,  int position) {

        questionsList=questionList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.tvQNo.setText(questionsList.getQuestionId()+"");
        holder.tvquestion.getLayoutParams().width= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        holder.tvquestion.setText(questionsList.getQuestion());
        holder.optA.setText(questionsList.getOptA());
        holder.optB.setText(questionsList.getOptB());
        holder.optC.setText(questionsList.getOptC());
        holder.optD.setText(questionsList.getOptD());
        holder.optA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Position :"+holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
        });
        holder.optB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Position :"+holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
        });
        holder.optC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Position :"+holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        holder.optD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Position :"+holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
        });
        holder.tvClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return questionList.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvquestion, tvClear,tvQNo;
        Button optA,optB,optC,optD;
        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvQNo=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLiveQuizQuestionNo);
            tvquestion=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLiveQuizQuestion);
            optA=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionA);
            optB=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionB);
            optC=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionC);
            optD=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionD);
            tvClear=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClearSelection);

        }
    } 
}
```

The only problem I am facing is the auto selection of unanswered options.

Please help me out in selecting the selected option only not the ones which are not selected. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views will be reused in your `RecyclerView` and hence you are having such a problem. In your case, you might consider having another array which stores the answers of your quizzes and can keep track of every item in your `RecyclerView`.

I would like to suggest modifying your adapter like the following. I have commented in some places. Hope that helps you to understand your problem.

```
public class LiveTestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LiveTestAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private int mItemSelected = -1;
    private List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList;

    private int[] answerList; // Get a list of your answers here.

    private DmLiveQuiz questionsList;
    private Context context;
    final DataHolder dh = new DataHolder();
    public List<Integer> myResponse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int qno;
    public String myQno;
    public int afterSub;
    DataHolder dataHolder;

    public LiveTestAdapter(List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList, Context context) {
        this.questionList = questionList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.live_quiz_display_format, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

        questionsList = questionList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.tvQNo.setText(questionsList.getQuestionId() + "");
        holder.tvquestion.getLayoutParams().width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        holder.tvquestion.setText(questionsList.getQuestion());
        holder.optA.setText(questionsList.getOptA());
        holder.optB.setText(questionsList.getOptB());
        holder.optC.setText(questionsList.getOptC());
        holder.optD.setText(questionsList.getOptD());

        // Now you need to modify the backgrounds of your option buttons like the following.
        if (answerList[position] == 1) holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
        else holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);

        if (answerList[position] == 2) holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
        else holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);

        if (answerList[position] == 3) holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
        else holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);

        if (answerList[position] == 4) holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
        else holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);

        holder.optA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                answerList[position] = 1; // Selected first option which is A
                Toast.makeText(context, "Position :" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.optB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                answerList[position] = 2; // Selected second option which is B
                Toast.makeText(context, "Position :" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.optC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                answerList[position] = 3; // Selected third option which is C
                Toast.makeText(context, "Position :" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.optD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                answerList[position] = 4; // Selected fourth option which is D
                Toast.makeText(context, "Position :" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.tvClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
                answerList[position] = 0; // Clear the value in the answerList
            }
        });
    }

    // Use this function to set the question list in the adapter
    public void setQuestionList(List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList) {
        this.questionList = questionList;
        this.answerList = new int[questionList.size()]; // This initializes the answer list having the same size as the question list
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return questionList.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvquestion, tvClear, tvQNo;
        Button optA, optB, optC, optD;

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvQNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLiveQuizQuestionNo);
            tvquestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLiveQuizQuestion);
            optA = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionA);
            optB = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionB);
            optC = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionC);
            optD = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionD);
            tvClear = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClearSelection);
        }
    }
}
```

Update - Please check that I have added `setQuestionList` function in the adapter. Please use this function to set your question list. Because, I think while initializing your adapter, the question list which is being passed is having a size of zero.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. After implementing your suggested code, I am getting following error.         E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.himsudha.agarni, PID: 28600
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
        at com.himsudha.agarni.adapters.LiveTestAdapter.onBindViewHolder(LiveTestAdapter.java:62)
       if (answerList[position] == 1) holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);                             
              This is the line showing error.......

Comment: Please try the updated code. I forgot the initialize the `answerList` variable and now its done in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and updated code but now the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 is showing   at          if (answerList[position] == 1) holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);

Comment: Please check the updated answer. And also please try to find an answer for some trivial mistakes of your own. Otherwise, we cannot help you.

Comment: But, you have not called the setQuestionList() method. At what position, I need to call it ? My mind is blowing, Moreover, do I need to declare "position" variable in onBindViewHolder() as final int position ? If I don't declare it final, errors are shown.....

Comment: Yes, you need to declare the position as final. And the `setQuestionList` function needs to be called when you are setting the question list in your adapter from your activity.

Comment: Sir, I can understand, my comments are irritating but I need your help. Please...

Comment: I understand and I am trying to help as much as I can. So far I think I have answered your question correctly. If you have other questions, you might ask them as a new question in StackOverflow. And please note that I cannot help you until you start helping yourself first!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir for your precious time and valuable suggestion. I shall let you know about the progress I make. thank you once again.

Comment: Dear Sir, after going as per your suggestions, I am not able to call setQuestionList(List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList) method. IndexOutOfBoundArray is showing. getData() is correctly fetching JSON Data
quizList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new LiveTestAdapter(quizList, getApplicationContext());
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
getData();

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for your help. Finally, I got the solution by posting the question in other post but I again thank you for so kind to me.   Final solution is only due to your solution , Sir. Thanks once again. May God Bless You.

Comment: Great to know that I could help. You are most welcome. :)